# How to save date in dd/mm/yy fromat in mongdb using mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I like to save the current date into the db with each request but I get time stamp as `ISODate("2020-01-31T10:20:46.000Z")` I like to save only 31-01-2020 into db for some functionality.How can I do it.

Comment: You should store date values as proper `Date` object rather than strings. It will save a lot of troubles in your future, e.g. sorting, manipulating, output formatting is much easier with `Date` objects than with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the field type to String first. And then create that string (say, using `momentjs`) and save it.

```
// Schema

{
  ...
  timestamp: String,
  ...
}

// Code

cons timestamp = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
// now save it...
```

An even better solution is as OP suggested, using `save` hook. Provided `timestamp` field is of type `String`:

```
const moment = require('moment');

// ...

mySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.timestamp = moment(this.timestamp).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
  next();
});
```

Comment: newTaskShema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.timestamp = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
next();
})
i tried like this but not working.Saying that moment is not defined

Comment: did you set the field type to string as I suggested? also, did you forget to call `next()` at the end of your hook by any chance?

Comment: you have to define moment which mean install it first by `npm install moment` and
in you code `const moment = require('moment')`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: let me check.I thought it was a function like date.now

Comment: replace it with `this.timestamp`.